# Considerations when making a jar into a J2EE shared library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, shared-libraries

I was curious about what being a "shared J2EE library" means, and the things that I should consider prior to saying that my JAR is a "shared J2EE library".

According to the Oracle docs, a shared J2EE library can be a "single, simple JAR". What does the term "simple" mean in this situation?
Are there restrictions on what a simple JAR that is a shared J2EE library can do or not do? Can my JAR spawn threads, do network I/O etc.? I understand that the J2EE framework was originally designed with libraries being treated as beans originally, and this bean design had some set of restrictions (eg. they weren't in charge of threads, network I/O etc.). But it seems like if I simply want my JAR to be a shared J2EE library, these restrictions for beans do not apply.

Finally, should my library be following the list of best practices for shared J2EE libraries, even if it is not a J2EE library, so that client web applications which refer to my library can follow best practices? Eg. Should my library be publishing both the "specification version" and "implementation version" and adhere to their semantics, or is this not our concern once we state we are not a shared J2EE library.

Comment: What documentation are you talking about here? If it really mentions "j2ee" then it is probably very old and not to be used as a source of information to understand JavaEE as it exists today.

Comment: [link]{https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/libraries.html#wp1070035} mentions "Best Practices for Using Shared J2EE  Libraries" at the very bottom and contains a list of things that shared libraries should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confusing about java library and J2EE library.

Each JAR can be a java library. There are a lot of examples: Spring, apache-commons, junit, etc...

All that you need to do in order to use a JAR as a library in your application is include it in your classpath.

Those JARs can perform all the **standar** task provided by java API: Sockets, NIO, files, concurrency, etc...

You can configure your server to load this kind of libraries (just a normal JAR) into your applications. In this case, the server will include all the content of the JAR in your classpath automatically, but it does not resolve any J2EE annotation from it (@EJB, @Inject, etc...)

On the other hand, a J2EE shared library can contains J2EE objects. That's, it can contain EJBs, Servlets, and so on.

Comment: My question is whether it is incorrect to call a normal JAR a J2EE library which doesn't contain any J2EE annotation inside it.

Comment: @hershey101 the document you link to specific includes standard jars in the collection of "J2EE jars". It sounds to me like a difficult way of saying that they are jars part of a deployed JavaEE application.

Comment: Ok. IMO we should use the name that better describe a thing.  So if our jar doesn't have any J2EE component then there is no reason to call it J2EE share library,  just share library